# Beveling edge problem

Tags: bevel

How i can fix this beveling problem. i am using a bevel modifier in my object:

[image]

Wire Frame:

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's a bit hard to understand what is the problem and what your trying to do, maybe show more pictures, show the wireframe, and explain more in detail  ;)

Comment: for example bevel won't work if it meets ngons or edge that is shared by more than 2 faces, it may be the case here?

Comment: i added wire frame view

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Maybe you just want to right click > Shade Smooth ?

Answer (score 1):

In "bevel modifier" under "Geometry" try changing "Miter Outer" and "Inner" settings. "Patch" or "Arc" usually gives better results. Changing "Inner" settings will blow up your mesh but you can dial it down from "Spread".